# Does google-cloud-functions retry on timeout?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm wondering if google functions always retry executing again whenever it timeout. eg "Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'"

I'm seeing the same execution_id running multiple times. Is it ok ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the logs duplicate some of the data they output. It only runs once. You can check it by pushing something to the DB during executing of the cloud function and see how many times it executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are not retried by default. You need to provision them to act this way. See the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries).

Comment: But I am getting retry to my backend flask application after every 40 seconds.